# WinRT XAML Toolkit NumericUpDown Template

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I am using WinRT XAML Toolkit in Windows Universal Application C#.
I want to change distance between plus(+) and minus(-) buttons and increase size of both buttons.

There are templates available for WPF but not for Universal app.

[Here is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHGOg.png)
Please advice me how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is in the toolkit [here](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/NumericUpDown/NumericUpDown.xaml).

You might be able to get what you want by changing these button styles to add the `Margin`:

```
<!-- DecrementButtonStyle -->
<Style
    x:Key="DecrementButtonStyle"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource NumericUpDownButtonStyle}"
    TargetType="RepeatButton">
    <Setter
        Property="Content"
        Value="&#x2796;" />
    <Setter
        Property="Margin"
        Value="5" />
</Style>

<!-- IncrementButtonStyle -->
<Style
    x:Key="IncrementButtonStyle"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource NumericUpDownButtonStyle}"
    TargetType="RepeatButton">
    <Setter
        Property="Content"
        Value="&#x2795;" />
    <Setter
        Property="Margin"
        Value="5" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Its breaking code with exception  in Windows Universal application.

Comment: Well, what's the exception and stack? BTW, I just realized the buttons in the template already have margins specified, so you might need to set them elsewhere in the template instead.